# Splunk query to map Exceptions to Endpoints

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Given a sample incoming request log:

`timestamp=2023-06-29 00:58:56,830 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 loglevel=ERROR traceid=8ae88647f7d41729 spanid=8ae88647f7d41729 message="httpUser=123456, httpClientId=osfgs9fgsd, httpStatusCode=400, httpUrl=/path/to/resource, httpMethod=PUT, httpRequestDuration=70"`

which will cause an Exception in the application, logged as:

`timestamp=2023-06-29 00:58:56,829 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 loglevel=ERROR traceid=8ae88647f7d41729 spanid=8ae88647f7d41729 message="triggerSplunkAlert, exceptionId=23ghe2eg-cvs-dfs-9bfa-4knkjl, errorCode=IllegalStateException,... (shortened out for brevity)`

I want to create a Table such as

| time | httpMethod | httpUrl | errorCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-29 00:58 | PUT | /path/to/resource | IllegalStateException |
| 2023-06-29 10:23 | POST | /path/to/whatever | NullPointerException |

But got no clue of how I could put Information of different Logs within the same table

Answer (score 1):

This answer *presumes* your fields are already properly extracted

If they are not, you'll need to do that first (and we can help you with it)

Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
((index=ndxA sourcetype=srctpA) OR (index=ndxB sourcetype=srctpB)) thread=* spanid=* loglevel=*
| stats values(errorCode) as errorCode values(httpUrl) as httpUrl values(httpMethod) as httpMethod max(_time) as _time by thread spanid loglevel
| table _time httpMethod httpUrl errorCode
```